# powercli script vs cronjob schtasks

Tags: powercli, windows-task-scheduler

I have a simple powershell script **file.ps1** which can be ran without any problem from powershell cli but cannot be ran from schtasks, could you please help me to find out where I am doing wrong?

**file.ps1**

```
$vDomain="192.168.1.1"
$vUser="user"
$vPassword="password"


#Connect to vCenter Server
PowerShell -Command "Connect-viserver -Server $vDomain -user $vUser  password $vPassword -WarningAction 0 | out-null"

#write down datastore_space_swindon
PowerShell -Command "Get-Datacenter | Get-Datastore | where {$_.Name -notlike "*ISO*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*template*" } | sort -Property FreeSpaceGB -Descending  > .\Datastore\htdocs\datastore_space_swindon"


# Disconnect from vCenter Server
#write-host "Disconnecting to vCenter Server $vcenter" -foreground green
PowerShell -Command "disconnect-viserver -confirm:$false | out-null"
```

**Ran from powercli(OK):**

> PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop> .\file.ps1
>       Disconnecting to vCenter Server
>       PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop>

**Ran from schtasks(NOT OK): scheduler task is just opening the file in notepad without run it.**

```
schtasks /create /tn "Datastore Space" /tr "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\file.ps1 \"" /sc minute /MO 1
```

**Also I tried with this command (NOT OK):**

> PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop> schtasks /create /tn "2" /tr
>   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe "&"
>   C:\Users\USER\Desktop\file.ps1 "" /sc minute /MO 1
>       Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
>       At line:1 char:91

**I hate windows Server!!**

Answer (score 0):

To create the task, try

```
schtasks /create /tn "Datastore Space" /tr "powershell.exe & C:\Users\USER\Desktop\file.ps1" /sc minute /mo 1
```

On recent OS, [New-ScheduledTask](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649810(v=wps.620).aspx) is one alternative to schtasks.exe.

You'd also need to load the VMware module (or snap-in, depending on the version) into your Powershell session, so the PowerCLI commands Connect-VIServer and Get-Datacenter will be recognized. Overkill, but here is the function I've been using for that:

```
function Enable-VMwarePowerCLI {
  if (Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.VimAutomation.Core) 
  {
    Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core # #vmware's module (6.5u2 > version > 6.1) defined its own prompt function and sets this var here "C:\program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\PowerCLI\Modules\VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk\VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.ps1"
    if ((Get-Module Vmware.VimAutomation.Core).Version.Revision -lt 6234650)` 
    { $Function:prompt = $originalPromptFunction }
  }
  else {Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core}
  (get-host).ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Green"
  $host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle='PowerCLI'
}
```

Within your file.ps1, I'm not sure what purpose is served by your `PowerShell -Command`.